# How to return to calling page, but with a slight difference, in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to call another MVC3 page(P2) and then return to calling page(P1). However the slight twist is that P2 needs to call itself, so the referrer can end up being P2.

So:

```
P1 - (P2 -> P2 -> P2) ->P1
```

So the question is how do I get P1's referrer URL and keep it and then use it later to go back to P1, regardless of the number of time P2 calls itself.

I did try and populate ViewBag.Referrer:

```
       <a href="@ViewBag.Referrer">Back</a>
```

using the following controller code, trying to only set it on the original call. However ViewBag.Referrer always seemed to pick up the P2 Referrer URL, even though in debug mode it was not resetting ViewBag.Referrer due to IsOriginalCall=0. It is weird. It is as if I am storing a pointer and not the value.

```
        public ViewResult Index(int id = 0, int IsOriginalCall = 0)
    {
        if (IsOriginalCall =1)
        {
        if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
        {
        ViewBag.Referrer = Request.UrlReferrer.LocalPath;
        }
        }
        ViewBag.SLIid = id == 0 ? 4 : id;

        return View(db.StdSection.Where(r=>r.InWizard).OrderBy(r=>r.Name).ToList());
    }
```

Thoughts and a solution would be hugely appreciated. I have been going around in circles on this one.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT, Attempt 2 with TempData:**

Calling code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Sections", "Index","SSLI2", new { id=item.Id, ReturnUrl = Request.Url.ToString() },null)
```

Controller:

```
    public ViewResult Index(string ReturnUrl, int id = 0)
    {
        if (ReturnUrl != "x")
        {
        //ViewBag.Referrer = Request.UrlReferrer.LocalPath;
          TempData["Referrer"] = ReturnUrl;
        }
        ViewBag.SLIid = id == 0 ? 4 : id;

        return View(db.StdSection.Where(r=>r.InWizard).OrderBy(r=>r.Name).ToList());
    }
```

View:

```
<a href="@TempData["Referrer"]">Back</a>
```

Which produces:

```
<a href="">Back</a> when P2 goes back to P2, but seems to use P2 referrer URL ????
```

Comment: As per your question this is the path P1(A) - (P2(->B) -> P2(->B) -> P2(->A)) ->P1. Do you passing referral url all the time like the above(P2 will refer to B(means P2 itself and at some level it have referal as A(means P1)) ? How do you identify that after calling the N times (P2) it should refer to P1 ? How do you find the value of "N" ?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the `ReferrerUrl` in from P1 querystring and then store the value in `TempData`.  It will then survive transition from one action call to another.

Another option would be to pass the `ReferrerUrl` in from P1 in the querystring and then put the value in a hidden input on P2.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ReferrerUrl)
```

or

```
@Html.Hidden("ReferrerUrl", ViewBag.ReferrerUrl)
```

then pick the value up on each post-back and render it as a hidden input value again.

### Edit

You could maybe try doing something like:

```
public ViewResult Index(string returnUrl, int id = 0)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    ViewBag.SLIid = id == 0 ? 4 : id;

    // This can be picked up in another action method.
    TempData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

    return View(db.StdSection.Where(r=>r.InWizard).OrderBy(r=>r.Name).ToList());
}
```

Then maybe render it using:

```
<a href="@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ReturnUrl)">Back</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for this great advice. I tried TempData, and the issue is the same ie it P2's url when I go from P2 to P2. Just checked the href tag, and it is "<a href="">Back</a>". It is empty. Yet when I hover over it, it picked up P2's url. ??????

Comment: An additional comment on the hidden field idea is that my page is a grid with hyperlinks, and is not a form. My interaction with the controller is therefore only via the hyperlinks.

Comment: I have edited my question above with additional attempt. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem I am having with TempData is that each time I return the View and then the user calls index again, TempData is lost. I guess this is because it is a new redirect, and TempData cannot exist beyond a redirect. The only method of getting this working thus far has been via a session variable.

Comment: This is what I am finding with TempData: "any data stored in TempData will be around for the life the current request and the next request only". Thus P1 -> (P2 -> P2) -> P1 Works. P1 -> (P2 -> P2 -> P2) -> P1 does not work.

Comment: You could try calling `TempData.Keep("ReturnUrl")` in the action method that handles your P2 `HttpPost`.  This should retain the value for one more hop.